# Should I check for future status deferred in boost asio async_ with use_future?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

If I use `boost::asio::async_` functions with `std::future` like here:

```
auto w_fut = boost::asio::async_write(*socket_, request, boost::asio::use_future);
```

Should I check if `w_fut`'s status is `std::future_status::deferred` and what should I do if it is?